# i want to create a image slider with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Acctually i want to make a simple image slider with java script,which is automatically change image after 2 seconds

Comment: the above question is not my real question its pasted by mistake

Comment: actually i want to create a image slider with my code my code is below

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51007801/edit) link below the question ...

Comment: html code                                                                                                                              </div>
 <div id="img">
  <img src="img1.png" alt="img1.png" id="slideimage">
 </div>

Comment: js code                                                                                                                                     var images = [ "img1.png",
         "img2.jpg",
         "img3.png",
         "img4.jpg" ];
 var i = 0;
 function slides() {
document.getElementByid("slideimage").src = images[i] ;
  if (i<(images.length-1))
   i++;
    else
    i=0

 }
 setInterval(slides, 2000)

Comment: please add your complete code on a snippet

Comment: @Maqsoodzaman you need to edit the original question. Voting down. Will vote back up when you correct it.

Comment: i am new.i dont know how do this

Comment: Right below the question, there are buttons for share, edit, and flag.  Click on edit and then change your question to what you actually want it to be with the code example.

Answer (score 2):

Use bootstrap carosal. its compatible almost every browser and easy to implement. No need to code from beginning.

use these files to include bootstrap to your project,

```
//css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

//js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Use below for slider

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=777&fg=555&text=First slide" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```